# Box API 2.0 - The owner of collaborated files/folder always gets wrong user

Tags: objective-c, box-api

I am using the Box Web API 2.0 for iOS development, and having trouble getting the owner of a collaborated folder.

I use an UITableView to display the children of a folder, and every time I click on an sub-folder, it updates the information on-the-fly and prints out its owner. My code is like this:

```
BoxObject *obj = [self.folder.children objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// the self.folder contains no file, just folders.
BoxFolder *folder = [Box folderWithID:obj.boxID];

[folder updateWithCallbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks> on) {
    on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response){
         if(folder.hasCollaboratorsObject)
            NSLog(@"%@ owner:%@",folder.name, folder.owner.username);
    });
}];
```

This always gives me the **login username** of this app, not the **"real" owner** of this folder.

But if I call the REST api like this

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
```

It returns real owner in the `owned_by` attribute.

Is that a bug of iOS WebAPI?

Comment: Are you using the supplied iOS SDK? That's actually based on the V1 API.

Comment: Well, I download the Web API from here: http://developers.box.com/onecloud/ , which supports ARC in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the V1 API, which is what the iOS SDK you're using is built against. If you'd like to be able to access this information, you'll want to call the /collaborations methods in V2 directly: http://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations

Comment: Thanks for your comment sean, but are you saying that the WebAPI I downloaded from http://developers.box.com/onecloud/ is V1 API? I am so confused...